# time difference between dates depending on id

Tags: r, data.table, difftime

I am looking for a `data.table` solution for a simple problem: I have data like this:

```
library(data.table)
data1 <- data.table(
  id = rep(1,3),
  date = as.Date(c("2016-03-30", "2016-03-31", "2016-04-05"))
)

data2 <- data.table(
  id = rep(2,2),
  date = as.Date(c("2016-03-30", "2016-03-31"))
)

data3 <- data.table(
    id = rep(3,4),
    date = as.Date(c("2016-03-30", "2016-03-31", "2016-04-05", "2017-04-05"))
    )  
data <- rbind(data1,data2,data3)
```

I would like to calculate the time difference between the first date for each unique id and each subsequent date for that unique id. I would like to end with the following, but there must be a one-line solution for this?

```
data_want <- data.table(
  t_dif = c(difftime("2016-03-30","2016-03-30",units="days"), 
            difftime("2016-03-31","2016-03-30",units="days"),
            difftime("2016-04-05","2016-03-30",units="days"),
            difftime("2016-03-30","2016-03-30",units="days"),
            difftime("2016-03-31","2016-03-30",units="days"),
            difftime("2016-03-30","2016-03-30",units="days"),
            difftime("2016-03-31","2016-03-30",units="days"),
            difftime("2016-04-05","2016-03-30",units="days"),
            difftime("2017-04-05","2016-03-30",units="days"))
)
data_want <- cbind(data, data_want)
```

Answer (score 1):

As it is a `data.table`, use `by` for grouping ('id'), get the `difftime` between the `first` value of 'date' and the 'date' column and assign (`:=`) to new column 't_dif'

```
library(data.table)
data[, t_dif := difftime(date, first(date), units = 'days' ), by = id]
```

-checking with OP's expected

```
> identical(data, data_want)
[1] TRUE
```